# How do I allow Google Authentication for React native webview

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-oauth

I created a webview app using react-native. The site rendered has a Google Authentication option (which is authenticating on Firebase) and use the pop-up method. This function works fine in web, but when trying to make this on the APP that I created, after selecting my account, it says that `Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared`.